# Normal force between objects

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If a book is kept on a table , will the book also apply a normal force on the table ? Then which of the two normal forces( one by book and other by table) would be considered as action force and reaction force ? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you can say that either is true, it is just a matter of definition. Usually we say that the force applied by the book on the table is the action and the table responds with the reaction.

Comment: Ok , so does the book  applies a normal force on the table .

Comment: Yes, otherwise where would the reaction from the table come from?

Comment: How many times  would this question be asked on this website?

Answer (score -2):

The book won't apply a normal force on the table, just a gravitational one. The reaction force of the gravitational force of the book is the normal force acting on the book.

Comment: I am of the opinion that the book does not apply a gravitational force. The gravitational force is applied by the earth on the book. Is this wrong ?

Comment: Implicit in Newton's Third Law is that the nature of the so-called action and reaction forces are of the same type... both normal or both gravitational. If there is a relation involving a normal force and gravitational force, Newton's Second Law must be involved.

Comment: This answer is wrong

Comment: This answer is completely out of scope of mine!!!